# How to add some "float" div to every page uing Nginx add_before_body or add_after_body?

Tags: html, nginx

For some reason, we have to add extra information for every page of our web site using Nginx add_before_body / add_after_body module.

We have done this, successfully add some text information for every page.

Now the problem is how to add some "float" div on every page using this method?

Any comments are welcome.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.